# ggplot2 error - replacement has 100 rows, data has 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Generate the following data frames.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(qicharts2)
plot1 <- qic(age,
              data    = tail(cabg, 100), 
              chart   = 'i',
              title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
              ylab    = 'Years',
              xlab    = 'Patient #',
              facet   = ~ gender)
p1 <- plot1$data
```

Then plot the following.

```
plot2 <- ggplot(p1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin = p1$lcl, ymax = p1$ucl, fill = "black", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_line(colour = "black", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, cl)) +
  geom_point(colour = "black" , fill = "black", size = 2) +
  ggtitle(label = "") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) + 
  facet_grid(~ p1$facet1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
plot2
```

When I try to add some geom_point() I get an error.

```
plot2 + geom_point(
    data = p1 %>% filter(sigma.signal == TRUE),
    color = "red"
  )
```

How do I fix this issue?

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   :    replacement has 100 rows, data has 2

I can add points on top of points in the same fashion on the *economics* data set with no issue. See below. Why am I having trouble in my prime example?

```
ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(
    data = economics %>% 
      filter(date > as.Date("2009-12-31")), 
    color = "red"
    )
```

Comment: What is `cabg`? Without it, the first block of code won't execute. Thanks.

Comment: It's a data frame that installs after you load the package `library(qicharts2)`. Is it not there for you?

Comment: Nope, not there for me :( Tried `data(cabg)` also and it says data not found. But then shut down R and restarted, and there it was... so problem was on my side!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is facet your new data.  That is,

```
plot2 + geom_point(
  data = p1 %>% filter(sigma.signal == TRUE),
  color = "red") + facet_grid(~ facet1)
```

[image]

Comment: Why does the new data have to be faceted via `facet_grid(~ facet1)` where the original was `facet_grid(~ p1$facet1)`. What's the principle difference? I guess I just don't get it although I am glad for the solution. Also, if I delete the `p1` from the original code chunk, my original solution works. What's going in with the facet?

Comment: Your original `facet_grid` was for `data = p1`, but when you add the points in the second step, you change `data`.  Before, it was trying to use the original `facet_grid` on a new data set which had a different number of rows.  There may be a more elegant way to define the data so that you only have to do it once.